# What is the time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, sorting

I want to sort first $\sqrt n$ minimum of an array of n elements. What is the time complexity?
My approach is :
First I have to find the $\sqrt n$ 'th minimum element (name it $x$) which has the time complexity of : $$O(n)$$
Second I have to make $x$ as pivot to place lower elements before $x$ using *Partition* algorithm which have time complexity of: $$O(n)$$
And then I have to sort these $\sqrt n$ elements using a sort algorithm that has minimum time complexity of:
$$O(\sqrt n \times log(n))$$
So the total time complexity should be:
$$O(n)$$
but the textbook has the answer of:
$$O(\sqrt n \times log(n))$$
I do not know why ? does it mean that:
$$n \in O(\sqrt n \times log(n))$$
Or I have mistake in my solution?
Best Regards

Comment: Looks like typo in textbook, because you must read all array => complexity is  not less $O(n)$

Comment: Is my approach for 3 steps correct?

Comment: IMHO, it is correct